# Java set timeout for URL.openStream()

Tags: java, url, java.util.scanner, urlconnection

I have a simple code that reads a line from a URL text file:

```
url = new URL(address);
Scanner s = new Scanner(url.openStream());
s.nextLine();
```

But the URL server is a bit slow and takes a few seconds to respond. Whcih I think is the reason why it throws an exception:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651) ~[?:?]
    at process.RunMe(MyFile2.java:115) [classes/:?]
    at process.Detect(MyFile2.java:31) [classes/:?]
    at Scheduler.PostHandler$3.run(MyFile.java:160) [classes/:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

How can I set a timeout for my code, or convert it to a way that I can set a timeout?

Comment: You'll have to show the actual exception and stack trace.  I don't think a timeout is the issue here.

Comment: @JimGarrison Just updated the question.

Comment: You are at the mercy of how fast the peer produces its output. You can't detect a semantic error in that output such as this one before it has occurred. Hard to see what good a timeout would do you.

Comment: Re your edit, taking a few seconds to response is not the reason for the exception. You had been told that three times already before your edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Scanner::hasNextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine())

Always use it before using `Scanner::nextLine` to avoid `NoSuchElementException`.

## Example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadURL {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(url.openStream());
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            String str = s.nextLine();
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        s.close();
    }
}
```